# Bootstrap Modal dialogs are instantly being dismissed when using FuelUX

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datagrid, modal-dialog, fuelux

I have a page that is using FuelUX's datagrid. I am using FuelUX's bundled version of bootstrap as well. Whenever a button on the page calls a bootstrap modal dialog, it instantly gets dismissed.

Comment: This is one I haven't seen - I added a test to http://tinkerbin.com/YKpPpzqE and couldn't reproduce the issue. Please click the green RUN button to start the JavaScript on that page if you take a look. Is it possible for you to reproduce the issue there by modifying it to make it closer to your own page? Thanks!

Comment: Just saw your answer, glad to hear it's working OK!

Answer (score 0):

This was a case of late night coding.

I had another double instance of Bootstrap on the page and they were stepping on each other.

Disregard.

Comment: Glad it wasn't something serious. :)